# Why is Chrome still submitting a form when a non-numeric value is entered in <input type=number>?

Tags: html, forms, validation, google-chrome

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC.

When binding a field in the view to an integer property in the model, MVC generates the HTML as follows, using the `type="number"` attribute:

```
<input data-val="true" 
  data-val-number="The field MessageControlIdFrom must be a number."
  id="Filter_MessageControlIdFrom"
  name="Filter.MessageControlIdFrom"
  type="number"
  value="">
```

This is fine, and Chrome recognises that it is expecting a number and adds increment/decrement controls to the input field.

If I attempt to submit the form when a non-numeric value is entered, I briefly see a validation message which I assume is generated by Chrome:

[image: Chrome number validation message: Please enter a number]

However the problem is that the form still submits and posts the data back to the server.  How can I prevent this happening?

**Update**

It appears that this affects Chrome v34 and v35; however in Firefox v30 the behaviour is as desired and the submission does not occur due to the validation error.

As pointed out by @pawel in the comments [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5x2y/) does work as expected (it does not submit) in Chrome v34 and v35.  Therefore I think this is something specific to the combination of my application and Chrome.

I will try and create a reduced application to enable reproduction of the issue.

Comment: Don't you use jquery validation? Standard packaged with MVC? Something like `@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x5x2y/ seems to work as expected: Chrome displays a bubble and the form is not submitted if the value is not a number.

Comment: @pawel thanks, I agree it works. Clearly I've missed something - will try to reduce the problem down to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like *[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/K3Cnz/)* on the client side: (jQuery)

```
// Prevent NULL input and replace text.
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="number"]', function (event) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
    if (this.value < 1) this.value = 0;
});

// Block non-numeric chars.
$(document).on('keypress', 'input[type="number"]', function (event) {
    return (((event.which > 47) && (event.which < 58)) || (event.which == 13));
});
```

But you should **always** validate on the server side as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I think this would have solved the problem, but I was more intrigued to discover *why* the browser would still allow the form to submit.

Comment: You can't (yet) rely on browsers to handle HTML5 inputs correctly. 
It also varies from browser to browser how they're currently handled.

Answer (score 1):

You should use HTML5 `pattern` attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />
```

`\d` is the regular expression for a number, `*` means that it accepts more than one of them.

I think it is a better way to prevent the form from submitting.This will surely work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; whilst this would have solved the problem, ASP.NET MVC automatically puts `<input type="number">` and I'm not sure if that can be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example here: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ where they make the user type in the value "correct".  I think that you could do something similar, except call `if(typeof $('#myTextArea') == "number")` and perform your check from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this would work, because the browser does not let you have the value of the `<input>` element unless it is numeric!

Answer (score 0):

I have now figured out why the form was still being submitted despite not entering a number.

There is a separate click event binding to the submit button on `$(document).ready()` like this:

```
$("#btnFilter").click(firstPage);
```

The `firstPage` function looks like this:

```
function firstPage() {
    $(".hiddenPager").val(1);
    $("form:first").submit();
}
```

I'm not sure this fully explains it, because the function is still calling `.submit()` which I would have thought Chrome would not honour due to the **abc** in the numeric input field.  However I now know what I need to change to stop the submit occurring.

Firefox behaves as expected and does not submit.